# How do I turn into reference into an et al. reference in the References section?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I want to turn any reference to a paper with more than 2 authors into First-Author-Last-Name et al. in the *References* section (but also in the actual text).

I am using natbib.

Is there a way to do that?

By the way, from Stackexchange, I found this:

http://blog.afcutt.in/2013/07/a-natbib-like-bibliographic-style-for.html

which could suit my needs. The only problem is that I need to truncate the list after the first author, and it truncates the list after the third author. I am not sure how to change that.

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!  You should probably make a MWE in order to both figure this out and to help others help you. http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe